# JPG, png and gif "This file type is not supported" in joomla 3.2.1

Tags: file-upload, joomla, joomla3.2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is it me or is this the new joomla release? It worked fine in 3.2 as far as I remember.
I tried png as well and gif. Different filenames.

For the unbelieving people, Legal extensions is:
bmp,csv,doc,gif,ico,jpg,jpeg,odg,odp,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,swf,txt,xcf,xls,BMP,CSV,DOC,GIF,ICO,JPG,JPEG,ODG,ODP,ODS,ODT,PDF,PNG,PPT,SWF,TXT,XCF,XLS
for me

Comment: If you feel that you have identified a bug in Joomla, please report it at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues so that it can be investigated and fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @betweenbrain I submitted it. In case you are an active member of the joomla team, come back at me please.

Comment: Thanks! I have confirmed the issue and have left a reply for you, and proposed fix, at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/2722. Thanks again for the report. See you on Github!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried uploading an image named java.jpg like your screenshot and it didn't work, then I tried php.jpg and didn't work as well. The same images with different filenames were uploaded fine, so I suppose it's the filename (java, php) and not the filetype (jpg) causing the error.